# Wordpress Plugin cannot edit Ajax URL?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have just made and installed a new Plugin into wordpress and i found out i had the wrong ajax url so i changed that. But the problem lies that it doesnt use the new URL i have in the file. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin. I have no idea how to get this to work.

Ajax:

```
function send_form() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url to sendmail1.php',
    data: {
      email: jQuery('#email').val(),
      name: jQuery('#name').val(),
      content: jQuery('#content').val(),
      phone: jQuery('#phone').val(),
      company: jQuery('#company').val()
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data.status == 'success') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#success').html('Thankyou for Your Email<br/> We will reply soon!');
        jQuery('#success').show();
      } else if (data.status == 'error') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#error').html('Oops! Something went Wrong!');
        jQuery('#error').show();
      };
    }

  });
```

Comment: Here is one nice tutorial. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
change the function

```
function send_form() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     url:   ajaxurl,

    data: {
      action:sendmail1fun,  // action


      email: jQuery('#email').val(),
      name: jQuery('#name').val(),
      content: jQuery('#content').val(),
      phone: jQuery('#phone').val(),
      company: jQuery('#company').val()
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data.status == 'success') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#success').html('Thankyou for Your Email<br/> We will reply soon!');
        jQuery('#success').show();
      } else if (data.status == 'error') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#error').html('Oops! Something went Wrong!');
        jQuery('#error').show();
      };
    }
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data.status == 'success') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#success').html('Thankyou for Your Email<br/> We will reply soon!');
        jQuery('#success').show();
      } else if (data.status == 'error') {
        jQuery('.formwrapper').hide();
        jQuery('#error').html('Oops! Something went Wrong!');
        jQuery('#error').show();
      };
    }

  });
```

add below code in the plugin page

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_ajax_sendmail1fun', 'sendmail1fun');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendmail1fun','sendmail1fun' );


function sendmail1fun(){

    // do in  sendmail1.php

    die();
}
```

?>